# Partial data loss in JSON deserialization between IoT Hub and ASA Input

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

> Setup is: **IoT Hub > input into > Stream Analytics**

I currently have (3) sensors and an azure gateway from ncd.io which are all reporting great into Azure IoT Hub.

Only two elements the record data from my sensors are making it through the auto JSON deserialization when setting up an IoT Hub input in ASA.

I have a device setup in IoT Hub which reports the correct **Device Twin** data from my local gateway as follows:

```
"reported": {
    "nodes": {
      "SN0013A20041DADDF7": {
        "firmware_version": 10,
        "transmission_count": 192,
        "reserve_byte": 0,
        "battery_level": 3.29406,
        "type": 1,
        "node_id": 0,
        "rssi": 100,
        "humidity": 27.93,
        "temperature": 22.28
      },
      "SN0013A20041DADD51": {
        "firmware_version": 10,
        "transmission_count": 175,
        "reserve_byte": 0,
        "battery_level": 3.29406,
        "type": 1,
        "node_id": 0,
        "rssi": 100,
        "humidity": 42.25,
        "temperature": 22.55
      },
      "SN0013A20041DADE33": {
        "firmware_version": 10,
        "transmission_count": 217,
        "reserve_byte": 0,
        "battery_level": 3.29406,
        "type": 1,
        "node_id": 0,
        "rssi": 100,
        "humidity": 39.33,
        "temperature": 22.62
      }
    },
```

I setup the input in ASA from my IoT Hub as JSON with no compression. The result in ASA looks great, but first position 'node' *seems to be excluded from the result*.

```
 [
  {
    "nodes": {
      "SN0013A20041DADE33": {
        "firmware_version": 10,
        "transmission_count": 164,
        "reserve_byte": 0,
        "battery_level": 3.29406,
        "type": 1,
        "node_id": 0,
        "rssi": 100,
        "humidity": 39.01,
        "temperature": 23.08
      }
    },
    "EventProcessedUtcTime": "2022-05-02T20:39:23.3568635Z",
    "PartitionId": 3,
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2022-05-02T19:55:43.2820000Z",
    "IoTHub": {
      "MessageId": null,
      "CorrelationId": null,
      "ConnectionDeviceId": "***",
      "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "***",
      "EnqueuedTime": "2022-05-02T19:55:43.1570000Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "nodes": {
      "SN0013A20041DADD51": {
        "firmware_version": 10,
        "transmission_count": 122,
        "reserve_byte": 0,
        "battery_level": 3.29406,
        "type": 1,
        "node_id": 0,
        "rssi": 100,
        "humidity": 42.09,
        "temperature": 22.62
      }
    },
    "EventProcessedUtcTime": "2022-05-02T20:39:23.3568635Z",
    "PartitionId": 3,
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2022-05-02T19:55:40.8290000Z",
    "IoTHub": {
      "MessageId": null,
      "CorrelationId": null,
      "ConnectionDeviceId": "***",
      "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "***",
      "EnqueuedTime": "2022-05-02T19:55:40.8130000Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "nodes": {
      "SN0013A20041DADE33": {
        "firmware_version": 10,
        "transmission_count": 163,
        "reserve_byte": 0,
        "battery_level": 3.29406,
        "type": 1,
        "node_id": 0,
        "rssi": 100,
        "humidity": 38.9,
        "temperature": 23.14
      }
    },
    "EventProcessedUtcTime": "2022-05-02T20:39:23.3568635Z",
    "PartitionId": 3,
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2022-05-02T19:55:03.7180000Z",
    "IoTHub": {
      "MessageId": null,
      "CorrelationId": null,
      "ConnectionDeviceId": "***",
      "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "***",
      "EnqueuedTime": "2022-05-02T19:55:03.6710000Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "nodes": {
      "SN0013A20041DADD51": {
        "firmware_version": 10,
        "transmission_count": 121,
        "reserve_byte": 0,
        "battery_level": 3.29406,
        "type": 1,
        "node_id": 0,
        "rssi": 100,
        "humidity": 42.22,
        "temperature": 22.65
      }
    },
```

There are really no options I can find to adjust this as it is all part of a single record... I can query the data I do receive and output it no problem.

[Example output in ASA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMkCG.png)

[Reference of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZLlt.png)

Comment: Do you mean that the `"reported"` first level wrapper is removed? Is your query `SELECT * FROM input`?

Comment: The first level **SN0013A20041DADDF7** in my reported query in the device returns as expected using `SELECT * FROM c` However, my problem is that when reading the raw input value in ASA the first wrapper element **SN0013A20041DADDF7** is not present before (or after) any query is applied.

Comment: Can you please try `SELECT c FROM c`. The wildcard behavior is to expand the first level, but with this syntax you should get the raw payload.

Comment: The query `SELECT c FROM c` results in an error in the Device inside IoT Hub and also in ASA.  I added an image link in my original post showing the result I get from a  `SELECT * FROM [input]` inside of ASA. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMkCG.png)

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get what's the issue. Could you please illustrate what result set you need? Or what logic you need applied?

Comment: Not sure about IoT Hub, but `SELECT [stream-input] FROM [stream-input]` should work in ASA.

Comment: The query in ASA `SELECT [input] FROM [input]` produces the same result as `SELET * FROM [input]`

Comment: [Illustration of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZLlt.png)

Comment: Thanks so much for the illustration, I was stuck thinking the issue was in the projection, not a missing row. Sorry about that ;) I'll try to reproduce on my side. If you have a sample file that shows the error, you can send it to askASA@microsoft.com

Comment: With the input message in your question and the following query, I get 3 rows out with no missing values. If you're in VSCode, could you please use the [preview data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/visual-studio-code-local-run#prepare-sample-data) option and share the content to see if I can reproduce the issue? `SELECT
 v.propertyname AS Node,
 v.propertyvalue.*
FROM input1 AS i
CROSS APPLY getrecordproperties(i.reported.nodes) AS v`

Comment: I had to omit "reported" from the query to collect a result `SELECT  v.propertyname AS Node,  v.propertyvalue.* FROM [Stream-Input] AS I CROSS APPLY getrecordproperties(i.nodes) AS v`. I have not been using VSCode but when I load the project and preview the data I get only the 2 & 3 row still.  I have never successfully viewed the first row on the ASA side from my input.  I will email my full input code from the device to the email referenced above.

Comment: As discussed by email, I can't reproduce the issue on the file. I recommended to read data from that same IoT Hub with another consumer client (service bus explorer, az cli, PowerShell...) to see whether it's an IoT Hub configuration issue (other consumers have the same issue) or an ASA issue (other consumers don't have the same issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that upon a deeper dive into the sensor, the missing sensor had an issue with reporting and was significantly behind the other two devices on the hub which caused it to be stripped from the result.

After power cycling the sensor and sampling the data I was able to receive all three sensors and pass them through to PowerBI with no issues.

Thanks @Florian-Eiden for all your help!